# Unable to call the methods defined in the subclass when instantiated with the Object of the Super Class in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, oop

I am facing an issue (due to my ignorance) where I am unable to call the methods defined in the subclass when instantiated with the Object of the Super Class in Obj C

Super Class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Automobile : NSObject
-(void)startVehicle;
@end


Sub Class 

#import "Automobile.h"

@interface Car : Automobile
-(void)startCar;
@end


Main Class 
//Works 
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc]init];
[myCar startCar]; 
//Works 
Automobile *myVehicle = [[Car alloc]init];
[myVehicle startVehicle]; // Due to inheritance 
// Does not work
[myVehicle startCar];
```

I am new to OOPS and would like some help to understand why does this not work

Best Regards
Shiva

Comment: It doesn't work because `Automobile` doesn't have a method named `startCar`.

Comment: I should clarify - the compiler will complain about the unrecognized method but at runtime it will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works, but the compiler will likely spit out some warnings about this practice (and this is indeed not a good thing most of the time, if not always...), like this one:

```
warning: 'Automobile' may not respond to '-startCar'
(Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments.)
```

I'm afraid I can't give you a complete answer focused on Objective-C practices because I'm not an Objective-C person. However I can point out some general principles that can be applied everywhere and will fix your specific issue.

---

I know your code is just an example but it seems like you could use a different solution and implement a generic method called just `start`, which can be used to start any instance of *Automobile*.

And then, if you **absolutely need** to call a `startCar` method  from an instance *declared* as *Automobile* (which may happen to be a *Car*) but you know that `startCar` should work only on *Car* instances, then it's a great idea to express that possibility in the *Automobile* interface itself, even though you know that `startCar` is a specific feature of *Car*'s only.

This is a way of expressing the idea that "if this *Automobile* instance happens to be a *Car* or derivative of *Car*, then something should happen when calling `startCar` here". However, if you **know** that this instance can only be a *Car*, then of course just declare the instance as a *Car* in the first place (but you already seem to be aware of that by looking at your code).

In conclusion, all you need to do is creating an empty implementation of `startCar` on *Automobile*, but the real thing will actually be implemented in *Car*.

Here is the whole fixed thing:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Automobile : NSObject
-(void)start;
-(void)startCar;
@end

@interface Car : Automobile
-(void)start;
@end

@implementation Automobile
-(void)start {
  NSLog(@"start Automobile");
};
-(void)startCar {};
@end

@implementation Car
-(void)start {
  NSLog(@"start Car");
};
-(void)startCar {
  NSLog(@"start Car (2)");
};
@end
```

Now this should work as expected:

```
// Works 
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc]init];
[myCar start]; 
// Works 
Automobile *myVehicle = [[Car alloc]init];
[myVehicle start];
// Works now!
[myVehicle startCar];
```

And the output will be:

```
2015-06-18 16:41:22.827 main[71] start Car
2015-06-18 16:41:22.828 main[71] start Car
2015-06-18 16:41:22.828 main[71] start Car (2)
```